# Nano save says Cancelled

Tags: linux, mac, nano

I am trying to save a file that was edited via nano. When I tried to save it is says 'Cancelled' and file is not saved.

This happens to only specific file. I can save other files. Keys I am pressing are ctrl+X and then yes to save; after this 'Cancelled' appeared.

[image]

Comment: Question edited

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /the/specific/file`?

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: So are you trying to create a new file with `nano`? or the file should be there and `no such file` is a surprise? When you wrote "specific file", I thought the file existed. But maybe you meant "specific path". Can you reveal the exact path?

Comment: File doesn't exist now because I have deleted it. Now I an unable to create a new file with same.

Comment: What OS are you running, precisely? You have tagged both macos & linux. Unless you're having issues with both, please use the correct tag. Where is the file located [or should be located]? What is the file? Did you use sudo?

Comment: I am logged into Linux ec2 from my Mac. I didn't use sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it came out to the the hidden locked file which was blocking/cancelling the new edit.

Use ls -a to see the hidden file as .[your_file].swp, next, try to remove it.

Once hidden file with extension .swp gets removed then it allows to edit and save file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).